Drop susbsequent records after a join where sequence number is greater than one sides join values
I have 2 dataframes, one with records of fallers (entered by office admin) in a given race and , the other serves as a lookup for identifying where a fall happened so obstacles encountered in a given race.
I want to merge these together to have a dataset at obstacle level to report on but my issue is dropping subsequent fences not encountered/eluded because a record did not reach this fence in a race.
I have a sequence number that can be used to say drop anything greater than obstacle upon which record fell but don't know how to implement this.
Faller DF (Entered by Admin)
fenceLabel & circuitNumber entered manually whilst the rest of fields are pulled from database
| fallerId | courseId | obstacleType | raceDistance | fenceLabel | circuitNumber |
|----------|----------|--------------|--------------|------------|---------------|
| 1        | 1        | steeple      | 2500         | A          | 1             |
| 2        | 1        | steeple      | 3500         | F          | 1             |
| 3        | 1        | water        | 3500         | A          | 2             |
| 4        | 2        | steeple      | 3000         | B          | 1             |
| 5        | 2        | steeple      | 3000         | B          | 2             |

Lookup Table (Static), corresponds to race details for first record in fallers DF
| courseId | obstacleType | raceDistance | startingfenceLabel | fenceLabel | circuitNumber | sequence |
|----------|--------------|--------------|--------------------|------------|---------------|----------|
| 1        | steeple      | 2500         | C                  | C          | 1             | 1        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2500         | C                  | D          | 1             | 2        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2500         | C                  | E          | 1             | 3        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2500         | C                  | A          | 1             | 4        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2500         | C                  | B          | 1             | 5        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2500         | C                  | C          | 2             | 6        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2500         | C                  | D          | 2             | 7        |
| 1        | steeple      | 2500         | C                  | E          | 2             | 8        |

I can join like so
(
    faller.merge(
        lookup,
        on=["courseId", "obstacleType", "raceDistance"],
        how="left"
)

This will give me all possible obstacles encountered in a race but how do I best keep obstacles that have been jumped and exclude the obstalces that haven't after the merge, through comparison of say fenceLabel_x, circuitNumber_x & fenceLabel_y, circuitNumber_y?
But say for record one in the fallers DF, I will only want to keep records up to sequence 4, therfore drop any records not encountered 5 thru 8 in sequence column.
How best to implement this?
Appreciate any help

Pre-filter the rows to exclude the values between 5-8 (or keep those below 5), then merge.

@mozway I need to take the inputted data for fenceLabel &  circuitNumber and then take all corresponding records in the lookup until that match and then drop the remaining rows, so needs to come after the merge right?

This lookup is just an example for the first record, other records will have other lookups associated too that will need to just keep records up to last fence/obstacle entered

In this case, post-filter using loc or query. The exact logic is not fully clear. Better provide a more explicit (and short) example, with the matching expected output.
